# Question regarding R code to do with rounding prime numbers

Tags: r, while-loop, primes

I need to have a function where if a number entered is a prime number, it must round it up to the next prime number and if it is not to round it down to the previous prime number.

I have this code to identify whether it is a prime number:

```
prime <- function(x) {
   if (x == 2) {
      print(3)
   } else if (any(x %% 2:(x-1) == 0)) {
      FALSE
     } else { 
      TRUE
   }
}
```

I want to add a while loop to the true and false where if the function is false, it must minus one until it is true and if it is true, it must add one until it is true again but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your prime checker,

```
prime <- function(x) {
  if (x == 2) {
    print(3)
  } else if (any(x %% 2:(x-1) == 0)) {
    FALSE
  } else { 
    TRUE
  }
}
```

We build the `new` function, we first check if our number is a prime, if so, add 1 until we reach the next prime. If it is not a prime, we minus 1 until it is.

```
new <- function(x){
  if (isTRUE(prime(x))){
    x = x+1
    while(prime(x) == FALSE){
      x = x+1
    }
    return(x)
  } else {
    while(prime(x) == FALSE){
      x = x-1
    }
    return(x)
  }
}
```

we get

```
> new(7)
[1] 11
> new(10)
[1] 7
```